# Forms Made Dynamically to Include Page Navigation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

This is a script for a dynamic form-generator that pulls from a spreadsheet.

```
function createForm2() {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("makechoice");

var dataRange = ss.getRange(2,1,40,20);
var data = dataRange.getValues();


var form = FormApp.create("Make a Test");

for (i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var title = row[0];
  var word = row[1];
  var qst = row[2];
  var ans1 = row[3];
  var ans2 = row[4];
  var ans3 = row[5];
  var ans4 = row[6];
  var fnb  = row[7];
  var url  = row[8];
  var ans5 = row[9];
  var ans6 = row[10];
  var ans7 = row[11];
  var ans8 = row[12];
  var ans9 = row[13];
  var ans10= row[14];
  var ans11= row[15];
  var ans12= row[16];
  var ans13= row[17];
  var ans14= row[18];
  var ans15= row[19];
  var ans16= row[20];




 if ( word == "M Choice") {form.addMultipleChoiceItem()                        
                 .setTitle(qst)
                 .setChoiceValues([ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4])
                 .showOtherOption(false);
                 }

 else if ( word == "Text") {form.addTextItem()
                                .setTitle(ans1)
                      }
 else if (word == "True/False")  {form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
                       .setTitle(qst)
                       .setChoiceValues(['True', 'False'])
                      }
 else if (word == "Video") { form.addVideoItem()
                           .setTitle(qst)
                           .setHelpText(qst)
                           .setVideoUrl(ans1);
                         }

 else if ( word == "Paragraph") {form.addParagraphTextItem()
                                .setTitle(qst)
                                }
 else if (word == "Grid") {form.addGridItem()
                         .setTitle(qst)
                         .setRows([ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4])
                         .setColumns(['Boring', 'So-so', 'Interesting']);
                        }
 else if (word == "List") {form.addListItem()
                         .setTitle(qst)
                         .setChoiceValues([ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4]);
                        }
 else if (word == "Image") {var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
                         form.addImageItem()
                         .setTitle(qst)
                         .setHelpText(qst) 
                         .setImage(img);



                         }

      }

      }
```

This creates the form in the exact order entered in the spreadsheet and allows the values and question types to be assigned through the spreadsheet.  Now, I've wanted to extend this to allow page breaks in the form, indicated from the spreadsheet, by adding this in.

```
 else if (word == "PageBreak") {form.addPageBreakItem()
                         .setTitle(qst);
```

That works fine.  But now I've noticed an interesting feature where you can assign a response for a question to jump to a specific page.  Within each response item you can enter in a `PageNavigationType`.  This is the step that I'm having trouble with.  I make a separate column to indicate a page number, however I'm not really sure how to link that to a specific page break that is made in the form.  An example I have looked at shows a page break being assigned to a variable, and then later the question response will call that variable.  The way I've set up my script doesn't allow me to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation to a new-to-create page after a choice/listitem is done at once, by both defining **and** refering to the page to be created.

EXAMPLE:

```
item.createChoice('Cats', form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('TestPag')),
```

This example is a modification aof the little script found on:
[this Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice)

It did the trick with me:)